# Retrofit custom callback that fires off instantly

Tags: android, callback, retrofit

I am using Retrofit for my Rest Client in my Android app.

I want to create a custom Callback like this:

```
public abstract class RestCallback<T> implements Callback<T> {

public abstract void success(T t, Response response, boolean inCache);

@Override
public void success(T t, Response response) {
    // todo
    success(t, response, false);
}

@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    // todo
}
}
```

But I want to also add a third call back that fires off instantly as soon as Retrofit get method is called.

Is this possible or am I going to have to write some kind of wrapper class for Retrofit methods that will do something as soon as those methods are called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [OkHttp Interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) to monitor and modify api calls.

Comment: Are they compatible with Retrofit?

Comment: They are, if you are using OkHttp (which is highly recommended - it's used implicitly by retrofit when imported into the project, or you can set it explicitly with retrofit builder's method setClient(new OkClient()) ). Older versions od retrofit had own RetrofitInterceptor class, I think